# Proof that a domain is normal (2)

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

> Let $A$ be a UFD in which $2$ is a unit. Let $f \in A$ be
> square-free, (i.e. $f$ is not divisible by the square of any prime of $A$). Then the ring $A[\sqrt {f}]$ is normal.

Let $K$ be the field of fractions of $A$ and let $α$ be a square root of $f$ in the
algebraic closure of $K$. Being $A$ a UFD, it is integrally closed in $K$. Hence, if $α ∈ K$, we have $α ∈ A$, then $A[α] = A$, and the assertion is trivial. Suppose that $α\notin K$. Then $α$ is algebraic over $K$ and the field of fractions of $A[α]$ is
$K[α]= K ⊕ Kα$. Hence, every element $t ∈ K[α]$ can be written in a unique way as
$t = x + yα$ with $x, y ∈ K$. The minimal polynomial of $t$ over $K$ is $X^2 − 2xX + (x^2 − y^2f)$; so *if $t$ is integral over $A$*, we get $2x ∈ A$ and $x^2 − y^2f ∈ A$. From these two facts, and the hypothesis that $2$ is a unit and $f$ square-free, we can obtain that $x,y\in A$, so that $t ∈ A ⊕ Aα = A[α]$, i.e. $A[α]$ is integrally closed in $K[α]$.

My problem with this proof is in the part in italics. Shouldn't we choose a $t$ integral over $K[\alpha]$? It seems to me that the argument above only proves that the elements of $K[\alpha]$ integral over $A$ are contained in $A[\alpha]$, and I don't think that being integral over $A[\alpha]$ implies being integral over $A$. Thanks for any clarify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $t \in K[\alpha]$ is integral over $A[\alpha]$, then $A[\alpha,t]$ is a finitely generated $A[\alpha]$-module. But $A[\alpha]$ is a finitely generated $A$-module, so that $B=A[\alpha,t]$ is a finitely generated $A$-module.

This is sufficient to see that $t$ is integral over $A$. Indeed, there is a finite free $A$-module $B_1$ with an $A$-surjection to $B$ and a map $\tau: B_1 \rightarrow B_1$ that reduces (in $B \rightarrow B$) to the multiplication by $t$. As $B_1$ is finite free over $A$, Cayley-Hamilton states that $\tau$ is integral over $A$. Thus the multiplication by $t$ (as a map $B \rightarrow B$) is itself integral over $A$, which means that $t$ is integral over $A$.

Comment: I couldn't follow your argument; we studied this proposition that maybe can work as well: *let $R\to X$ be an $R$-algebra; then $x\in X$ is integral over $R$ iff there exist a $R[x]$-module $M$ which is faithful and finitely generated as $R$-module*. It seems to me that if we set $M:=A[\alpha,t]$, $R:=A$ and $x:=t$, the hypothesis of the proposition are satisfied and the result is $t$ integral over $A$.

Comment: This proposition works (instead of the argument in the second paragraph), certainly. You can see this paragraph as a sketch of proof of your proposition.